# Can Rock Giants reflect projectiles?

Tags: diablo-iii

While fighting some Rock Giants, I'm finding my tremendously large [Arcane Orbs](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/arcane-orb) (with Celestial Orb) bouncing back at me and my friends, damaging us!

How can I avoid annihilating my friends with magic, and what's causing my orbs to get reflected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rock Giants apparently have an ability that puts up a swirly shield that will reflect projectiles away from it, and cause said projectiles to **damage you and your party**. This is especially dangerous if you have large projectiles and/or lots of friends playing with you.

[image: I'd freehand circle, but...]

Anytime you see this swirly garbage, switch to a non-projectile attack (e.g. Disintegrate, Blizzard, Electrocution, etc.).

[image: Arcane pinball]

Comment: **I'm famous!**